# Other Maven project import can not be resolved

Tags: maven

In my Eclipse maven Project pom.xml, there are two other maven project dependencies(project1 and project2). I was able to use all those classes in my Project. I did git pull which had pom.xml changes('htmlunit' dependency was added). Then my project started showing error 'import can not be resolved' for the classes defined in project1 only and project2 imports are fine. And I am able to build, deploy the project successfully in terminal but getting those errors in my eclipse IDE only.

Can someone help me how to solve this error "other maven project classes import cannot be resolved"?

Is there anything to be taken care when pom.xml is modified?I tried project->clean, maven->update project.

Comment: maven update with forced snapshot/release dependencies

Comment: Thank you. Force update in my eclipse IDE is worked. tries this: right click on my project -> maven -> update project -> force update of snapshots/releases.